How to make data from dpdk mempool readable for a java application?
I am currently building a network traffic visualization application with a java-based backend which is designed to analyze network traffic and provide REST api service to a web frontend. To guarantee high throughput up to 40Gb/s, i plan to use dpdk for packet capturing but i don't know how to access the packet data from the java application.
I have read some documentations of dpdk but i can't find api for something like shared memory that can be read from an application outside the dpdk environment.
